# Python function that calculates averages from another function

Tags: python, average

I cant get the return values (a,b,c,d) of `randomCrosses` function to feed into the average function when they are used together in the `randomAverage` function. someone please tell me what I'm missing!

```
def randomCrosses():
    """Draws four random crosses of randomized values between 0-400 and returns the four random values a,b,c,d""" 
    a = r.randint(0,400)
    drawCross("Darkgreen",(a, 10))
    b = r.randint(0,400)
    drawCross("blue",(b, 10))
    c = r.randint(0,400)
    drawCross("magenta",(c, 10))
    d = r.randint(0,400)
    drawCross("limegreen",(d, 10))
    return(a,b,c,d)


def average(a,b,c,d):
    """Calculates and returns the average of four values a,b,c,d"""
    mean = (a+b+c+d)/4
    return mean


def randomAverage():
    """Randomizes four values 0-400 for a,b,c,d and then calculates the average of these values""" 
    a,b,c,d = randomCrosses()
    average(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? What happens if you run your code?

Comment: You're missing a return statement in `randomAverage`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return-statement in `randomAverage`:

```
def randomAverage():
    """Randomizes four values 0-400 for a,b,c,d and then calculates the average of these values""" 
    a,b,c,d = randomCrosses()
    return average(a,b,c,d)
    #  ^-- you need this
```

Right now, when you call `average` inside `randomAverage`, the function (`average`) works fine and returns what it should.  However, your code stops there.  Without a return-statement inside `randomAverage` that returns what `average` returns, the value returned by `average` is simply ignored.